# send file from android to java using jsp

Tags: java, android, file, jsp, http

I have an Android app, and I want to send a file to my jsp server. I can conect with my jsp server, I can send the file, but I dont know how I can receive it. This is my code. I send image to the server, but it not received... I have a new file but it have 0 bits :SS

Sorry for my bad English

SERVER JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import ="java.util.List"%>
    <%@ page import ="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@ page import ="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
    <%@ page import ="java.io.InputStreamReader"%>
      <%@ page import ="java.io.OutputStream"%>
      <%@ page import ="java.io.*"%>
    <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload" %>  
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory"%>  
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*"%>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>


<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Recibir FIchero</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
 // or "data" 
System.out.println("Recibiendo Archivo...");
final String path = "C:\\Users\\Public";
final Part filePart = request.getPart("image");
final String fileName = "recibido.jpg";

OutputStream out2 = null;
InputStream filecontent = null;
final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

try {
    out2 = new FileOutputStream(new File(path + File.separator
            + fileName));
    filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();

    int read = 0;
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((read = filecontent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out2.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }
    writer.println("New file " + fileName + " created at " + path);

} catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
    writer.println("You either did not specify a file to upload or are "
            + "trying to upload a file to a protected or nonexistent "
            + "location.");
    writer.println("<br/> ERROR: " + fne.getMessage());

    System.out.println("error!!!!");
    fne.printStackTrace();


} finally {
    if (out2 != null) {
        out2.close();
        System.out.println("canal cerrado!!!!");

    }
    if (filecontent != null) {
        filecontent.close();
    }
    if (writer != null) {
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("fichero cerrado!!!!");
    }
}



%>
</body>
</html>
```

ANDROID CLIENT

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpClient mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            String url = "http://81.36.204.206:8080/Servidor1/setFile.jsp";
            File file = new File(archivo[0]);
            try {

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);  
                multipartEntity.addPart("Title", new StringBody("Title"));
                multipartEntity.addPart("Nick", new StringBody("Nick"));
                multipartEntity.addPart("Email", new StringBody("Email"));
                multipartEntity.addPart("image", new FileBody(file));
                httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

                mHttpClient.execute(httppost, new PhotoUploadResponseHandler());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
```

archivo[0] example: "/sdcard/WhatsApp/Profile Pictures/34654826312.jpg"

Comment: So every time you try you see a new file C:\Users\Public\recibido.jpg of size 0? You delete the file before the next try?

Comment: `File file = new File(archivo[0]);` Please give an example of the value of `archivo[0]`.

Comment: is the path of the local file. example: "/sdcard/WhatsApp/Profile Pictures/34654826312.jpg" copy and paste from debugg ^^

Comment: I think the problem is in the server. what do you think?

Comment: Maybe. But you are not logging enough in the server to see what actually happens. For instance place a log sratements in the read loop where you print the value of read. Further you should also extract the other parameters as Title and Nick. And on client side you do not read the response. You should do that to see what the server sends back.

Comment: If,in the server, I change \\\request.getPart("image")/// for request.getPart("XXXX"); the result is the same...

Comment: What do you mean with the result is the same? Please be more exact and precise.

Comment: the result is that I get a file with size=0.

Comment: That is silly because if you try to get the value for Title and Nick you would not extract it to file but to a string and then log it. So please do so. You will not have to use an inputstream then i think.

Comment: how can I get the value of Nick an title? I dont know use getPart :S

Comment: Don't know. I never used that component. Google for examples.

Comment: You are sure that the file is send? You have no exceptions? But then you did not implement PhotoUploadResponseHandler so how do you know?

Comment: no exceptions. The PhotoUploadResponseHandler run after the send, and it is ok I think.

Comment: heyyy in the server, the line: "filecontent = filePart.getInputStream();" I have a nullpointerexception here!!

Comment: So filePart==null; Check before use. Log it. Write it to the page and do't execute further code. Let your client read the returned page so the user sees the problem.

Comment: if I do : request.getparts.size, its is 0. 0 parts?? then the mistake is in the client?

Comment: I am doing it in jsp file, not in a servlet!!

Comment: I checked your client code and it is ok. The returned page is available in PhotoUploadResponseHandler. Have you implemented that correctly to see the returned page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recieve the file you have to write it to the external storage and you must request the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

When saving a file to internal storage, you can acquire the appropriate directory as a `File` by calling getFilesDir() or getCacheDir():

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
```

[more examples here...](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Comment: the server is a PC in Java, no an Android app